# Media Player Force Closes on Back Button Click

Tags: java, android, media-player, back-button, forceclose

When i press back button,media player force closes ,
here is main java file

```
package com.mp.mpeplayer;
    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private ImageButton btnForward;
    private ImageButton btnBackward;
    private ImageButton btnNext;
    private ImageButton btnPrevious;
    private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
    private ImageButton btnRepeat;
    private ImageButton btnShuffle;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songTitleLabel;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
    // Media Player
    private  MediaPlayer mp;
    // Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private SongsManager songManager;
    private Utilities utils;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
        btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
        btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

        // Mediaplayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        utils = new Utilities();

        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

        // By default play first song
        playSong(0);

        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Forward button click event
         * Forwards song specified seconds
         * */
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                }else{
                    // forward to end position
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Backward button click event
         * Backward song to specified seconds
         * */
        btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                }else{
                    // backward to starting position
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Next button click event
         * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
         * */
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check if next song is there or not
                if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                }else{
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Back button click event
         * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
         * */
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                }else{
                    // play last song
                    playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Repeat button
         * Enables repeat flag to true
         * */
        btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isRepeat){
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isShuffle = false;
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Shuffle button
         * Enables shuffle flag to true
         * */
        btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isShuffle){
                    isShuffle = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isShuffle= true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isRepeat = false;
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Play list click event
         * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
         * */
        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Receiving song index from playlist view
     * and play the song
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                     int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 100){
             currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
             // play selected song
             playSong(currentSongIndex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to play a song
     * @param songIndex - index of song
     * */
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update timer on seekbar
     * */
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }  

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     * */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
               long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

               // Displaying Total Duration time
               songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
               // Displaying time completed playing
               songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

               // Updating progress bar
               int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
               //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
               songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

               // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
           }
        };

    /**
     *
     * */
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    /**
     * When user starts moving the progress handler
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    /**
     * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }

    /**
     * On Song Playing completed
     * if repeat is ON play same song again
     * if shuffle is ON play random song
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
        if(isRepeat){
            // repeat is on play same song again
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else if(isShuffle){
            // shuffle is on - play a random song
            Random rand = new Random();
            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else{
            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
     }

}
```

Error log is here,

```
 09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915): java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at com.mp.cycloneplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity$1.run(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:317)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
09-24 12:49:25.398: E/AndroidRuntime(6915):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
if(mediaPlayer!=null)
{
     if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
     mediaPlayer.stop();
     mediaPlayer.release();
}
finish();
```

Please vote if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to release your media player object in `onBackPressed()` method, try thi in your `onBackPressed()` method :

```
if(mp != null)
{
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
}
finish();
```

Or you can try the below code :

```
@Override

 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
 {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
     {
          if(mp != null)
          {
              mp.stop();
              mp.release();
          }
          finish();
          return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my phone, so code snippets would be hard...
Your problem is that the thread checking the duration is still running after the MediaPlayer is lost. You have to add some safeguards in the Handler and make sure the background thread is joined when it's no longer necessary.
If you need, I'll be more specific once I'm near a PC.